# why does subfigure show wrong reference number?

Tags: floats, subfloats

I am using \begin `{figure}-\end {figure}` for one figure and `\begin {figure} \subfigure{} \end {figure}` for multiple figures joined on a page. (By using `\usepackage{subfigure}`)
When I refer the `\subfigure` (multiple figure in one figure label, referring number shows wrong. for example, it should be Figure (5), but it shows Figure (3.1)
This is one of my subfigure code.

```
\begin{figure}{
\centering
\caption{Validation of Revolving by Categories}
\subfigure [Frequency of Revolving (Promotional Cash)]{
    \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{category_a1.png}}
\subfigure [Conditional Expectation (Promotional Cash)]{
    \includegraphics[scale=0.8] {category_a2.png}}
\subfigure [Frequency of Revolving (Regular Cash Withdrawal)]{
    \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{category_b1.png}}
\subfigure [Conditional Expectation (Regular Cash Withdrawal)]{
    \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{category_b2.png}}
\subfigure [Frequency of Revolving (Retail Transactions)]{
    \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{category_c1.png}}
\subfigure [Conditional Expectation (Retail Transactions)]{
    \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{category_c2.png}}

}
%\scriptsize{Notes. (a) depicts }


\label{fig:revol}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Don't use `subfigure` package. It is obsolete and the new one is `subfig` package.  Use `subcaption` package that provides the same functionality.

Answer (score 3):

`subfigure` package is obsolete. Use `subfig` package instead. I prefer using `subcaption` package which provides `subfigure` environment.

```
\documentclass[12pt,demo]{elsarticle}
%%%\usepackage{subfig} do not use load this package

\usepackage{subcaption} %%% 

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{category_a1.png}
    \caption{Frequency of Revolving (Promotional Cash)}
    \label{subfig:cash}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.8] {category_a2.png}
    \caption{Conditional Expectation (Promotional Cash)}
    \label{subfig:pcash}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{category_b1.png}
    \caption{Frequency of Revolving (Regular Cash Withdrawal)}
    \label{subfig:frwith}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{category_b2.png}
    \caption{Conditional Expectation (Regular Cash Withdrawal)}
    \label{subfig:cewith}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{category_c1.png}
    \caption{Frequency of Revolving (Retail Transactions)}
    \label{subfig:frtra}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{category_c2.png}
    \caption{Conditional Expectation (Retail Transactions)}
    \label{subfig:cetra}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Validation of Revolving by Categories}
\label{fig:revol}
\end{figure}

Refer to figure~\ref{fig:revol}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For examples using `subfloat` from `subfig` package, refer to its manual or this site. If you need any help feel free to ping. It is almost same as your example in the question with `\subfigure` replaced by `\subfloat`

Answer (score 3):

The causes of the incorrect number in the cross-reference to the figure as a whole are (i) the incorrect use of `{...}` to encase the material after `\begin{figure`} and (ii) the fact that the `\label{fig:revol}` statement *does not occur immediately after* the corresponding `\caption` statement (viz., `\caption{Validation of Revolving by Categories}`). Instead, the statement `\label{fig:revol}` is deferred until *after* various subfigures, each with their own implicit caption statements, have been processed. Hence LaTeX ends up associating the label with one of the subfigures instead of with the figure as a whole.

The `figure` environment does *not* take an explicit argument that needs to be delimited in curly braces. Get rid of the braces and/or -- I recommend *and* -- place the `\label` statement immediately after the associated `\caption` statement, and the problem with the incorrect cross-reference is solved.

A separate matter: as @HarishKumar has already noted in his separate answer, the `subfigure` package is considered obsolete. Use either `subfig` or `subcaption`.